# UITableview - set different custom cells depending on current day

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UItableview and 2 custom cells, both have a label of the current day at the top. And then one custom cell we can call A has one label below the dayLabel, and then custom cell B, has two labels below the dayLabel.

Then I have 7 rows in 1 section for this. One row for each day. And it is always ordered so the current day is at the top. And what I am now trying to do is to have the cells where the day label is saturday and sunday, be of cell type A, and the rest of the cells be of cell type B.

So basically no matter what the days is, the cell where the dayLabel is either saturday or sunday I want of cell type A, and the rest of cell type B. Here is my code for my tableview.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *daysOfTheWeek = @[@"Sunday",@"Monday",@"Tuesday",@"Wednesday",@"Thursday",@"Friday",@"Saturday"];
    NSArray *mealsforAlbany = @[@"Breakfast", @"Lunch", @"Dinner"];
    NSArray *mealsforUnion = @[@"Lunch", @"Dinner"];
    self.mealsArray = ([currentUserAll[@"school"] isEqualToString:@"Union College (NY)"])? mealsforUnion : mealsforAlbany;
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSInteger dayNumber = [cal component:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]] - 1; // Sunday gives 0

    //The following 3 lines create a new array starting with today's weekday
    NSMutableArray *temp = [[daysOfTheWeek subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(dayNumber, 7- dayNumber)] mutableCopy];
    [temp addObjectsFromArray:[daysOfTheWeek subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 7 - temp.count)]];
    self.weeksRotation = temp;

    }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 7;
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 7;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.weeksRotation[section];

//    return nil;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return 75;

}
```

And here is cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSInteger feedIndex = indexPath.row;

if (feedIndex < 7) { //set this a varibale and depending on if statements set its vaule

    TwoMealsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TwoMealsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //cell.textLabel.text = self.mealsArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor = garnetColor;

    cell.dayLabel.text = self.weeksRotation[indexPath.row];

    [cell.firstMealBtn setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; //set this as a vaible for if stamtens
    [cell.secondMealBtn setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    cell.dayLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [cell.firstMealBtn setTitle:@"Lunch" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.secondMealBtn setTitle:@"Dinner" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    cell.firstMealBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.secondMealBtn.tag = indexPath.row;


    [cell.firstMealBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(firstMealBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.secondMealBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(secondMealBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    return cell;
}
}
```

Here I have it all set as cell type B, but what I need is for saturday and sundays cells to be of type A and the rest of B.

Thanks for the help in advance.

**EDit**

For example for School A, Dining Hall 1 I have Monday- Friday I want two meals and then Saturday and Sunday I want 1. But School A Dining Hall2, I have Monday- Friday 4 meals, Saturday 2 meals and Sunday 3 meals. Is the only way to just have a bunch of if statements for each case?

Comment: Why do you have 7 sections each with 7 rows. This is a modification of the code I gave you in a different question, where we had seven sections (one for each day), and either two or three rows per section depending on the meals for that day. Now, since you're adding the meal labels all to one cell (and not using section headers), you should only have one section with 7 rows (as far as I can tell).

Comment: @rdelmar that was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to dequeue the cell you want depending on the value of self.weeksRotation[indexPath.row].

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([self.weeksRotation[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Saturday"] || [self.weeksRotation[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Sunday"]) {

        OneMealTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OneMealCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        //set up the cell
        return cell;
    }else{ 

        TwoMealsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TwoMealsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.textLabel.text = self.mealsArray[indexPath.row];
        cell.backgroundColor = garnetColor;

        cell.dayLabel.text = self.weeksRotation[indexPath.row];

        [cell.firstMealBtn setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; //set this as a vaible for if stamtens
        [cell.secondMealBtn setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        cell.dayLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        [cell.firstMealBtn setTitle:@"Lunch" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.secondMealBtn setTitle:@"Dinner" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        cell.firstMealBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
        cell.secondMealBtn.tag = indexPath.row;


        [cell.firstMealBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(firstMealBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.secondMealBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(secondMealBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

        return cell;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

There are any number of ways you could accomplish your task, but given the fact that you have multiple dining halls at multiple schools, there's going to be some complexity to the logic. One way to do it would be to have multiple daysOfTheWeek arrays, one for each different case. Instead of a simple array, it would be an array of dictionaries. This puts most of the complexity in having to create a bunch of these arrays, but keeps the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath simpler. Something like this,

```
NSArray *albany1 = @[@{@"day":@"Sunday", @"meals":@[@"Lunch", @"dinner"]}, @{@"day":@"Monday", @"meals":@[@"Breakfast",@"Lunch", @"dinner"]},@{@"day":@"Tuesday", @"meals":@[@"Breakfast",@"Lunch", @"dinner"]},@{@"day":@"WednesDay", @"meals":@[@"Breakfast",@"Lunch", @"dinner"]},@{@"day":@"Thursday", @"meals":@[@"Breakfast",@"Lunch", @"dinner"]},@{@"day":@"Friday", @"meals":@[@"Breakfast",@"Lunch", @"dinner"]},@{@"day":@"Saturday", @"meals":@[@"Lunch", @"dinner"]}];

NSArray *albany2 = ....

// etc. one array for each dining hall
```

You would use whatever information you're sending from the first controller to choose the correct array, then pass that array to those lines that rearrange the array to make today's weekday the first element (so you would still have just one weeksRotation array). You would need as many different cells as you have different number of meals, so probably four cells for one, two, three, or four meals per day. You could then use a switch statement in cellForRowAtIndexPath to choose which cell to dequeue.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    int buttonNumber = [self.weeksRotation[indexPath.row][@"meals"] count];

    switch (buttonNumber) {
        case 1: {
            OneMealTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OneMealCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            // configure the cell
            return cell;
        }
        case 2: {
            TwoMealTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TwoMealCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            // configure the cell
            return cell;
        }
        case 3: {
            ThreeMealTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ThreeMealCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            // configure the cell
            return cell;
        }
        case 4: {
            FourMealTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FourMealCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            // configure the cell
            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: okay yes but I have a bunch of ways that the cells need to be arranged, about 20, and I feel like there is a better way to do that? See this question for details.

Comment: @daveneedleman, I don't see anything in your edit that would require  20 arrangements. If there are really that many, then you need to more fully describe your requirements. How is the user going to choose the dining hall? Do you want one dining hall per table view, or do you want to show all the dining halls for a school in one table view.

Comment: its one per tableview, and they have already chosen that and I send that data to the tableview as a string wight he dining hall they have chosen.

Comment: @daveneedleman, I edited my answer to give you one way that might work for you.

Comment: okay but then where is albany1/ albany2 used in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: also this line `NSInteger buttonNumber = [self.weeksRotation[indexPath.row][@"meals"] count];` Throws this exception `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString objectForKeyedSubscript:]`

Comment: @daveneedleman, As I said, you use whatever info you send from the initial controller to pick which of the arrays you use. Then you do the shuffling to create the weeksRotation array, and that's what gets passed to the data source methods. The way the arrays are set up, it should work with any of the arrays, since they contain the information within them to determine which cell to dequeue. As for that error, have you created the array like I showed, and then used that to create the weeksRotationArray? What does a log of [self.weeksRotation[indexPath.row] show?

Comment: what do you mean by weekRotation array, I was confusing that daysOfTheWeekArray.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63238/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-dave-needleman).